# How to display pdf file on a template from upload from admin only

Tags: python, django, models

I want to serve PDF document on my website using the django admin only. I am totally lost this is what i have as my model

```
class Examination(models.Model):
    examination_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='examination'
        verbose_name_plural='examinations' 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.examination_name


# Create your models here.
class Year(models.Model):
    examinations = models.ForeignKey('Examination')
    examination_year = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='year'
        verbose_name_plural='years'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.examination_year


class PastQuestion(models.Model):
    years = models.ForeignKey(Year)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/', max_length=100,)
    posted_by = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.years
```

Then I get this error when i try to open PastQuestion from my admin interface.
TypeError at /admin/PastQuestion/pastquestion/

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Year found how do I do this properly

This is the error I got when i click on PastQuestion

TypeError at /admin/PastQuestion/pastquestion/

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Year found

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/PastQuestion/pastquestion/
Django Version:     1.10
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Year found

Exception Location:     /home/tomms/Desktop/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 78
Python Executable:  /home/tomms/Desktop/project/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.9
Python Path:

['/home/tomms/Desktop/project/source',
 '/home/tomms/Desktop/project/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/tomms/Desktop/project/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/tomms/Desktop/project/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/tomms/Desktop/project/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/tomms/Desktop/project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/tomms/Desktop/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/tomms/Desktop/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 23 Aug 2017 01:54:37 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template /home/tomms/Desktop/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 82

Comment: that looks about right ... whats the problem?

Comment: i don't know how to proceed from here and i get error when i try to render year

Comment: what error do you get? Would you mind posting that in the question